# How to send a push notification on app (andorid/ios) that uses webview and on the back-end is .NET WebAPI

Tags: c#, reactjs, .net, sql-server, react-native

I am working on a booking application, so I need to create a notification that will be displayed 24h before the booking as a reminder and asking in the notification is the client coming or not.
We use react(for android and ios it's a webview) on front, .NET on back as a WEB API and SQL Server for the database.
Bookings are on 1 hour, I had an idea of creating a webjob that will run every hour and query the database what are the bookings that are in one day ahead and to send to the specific users the message and ask them are they coming or not.
Is this possible or I need to switch from a webview to react native, and any suggestions about this idea of mine?

Answer (score 1):

you sould use webserive and use time based timer for opening popup page for all users in other times.(and query the database what are the bookings that are in one day ahead and to send to the specific users the message and ask them are they coming or not. Is this possible or I need to switch from a webview to react native, and any suggestions about this idea of mine)